# How to get a js object from a DIV?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I get the google maps object from my DIV?

This is what I did to set the map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOptions);
```

Then I want to get the map to do this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: initialLocation,
  map: document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
  title:"AJAX!"
});
```

Of course this produces an error.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property  : [object HTMLDivElement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if it expects a map object then you need to keep track of that map object so you can use it in other functions. Something like:

```
var map;

function CreateMap(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function AddMarker(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: initialLocation,
      map: map,
      title:"AJAX!"
    });
}
```

Comment: Thought DIV could keep it somehow. But that was my other answer.

Comment: @code-gijoe: unlikely, `div` is just html and is only stored as text. Technically you could probably serialise the map object and store it as text somehow, but even then it wont be the exact same object and you would have to reapply it to the div after changing it... basically, this is not what you want to try and do.

Comment: if you have multiple maps you could use some sort of dictionary lookup to store the map objects and just store the keys as data-attributes on the div. But only bother with this if you have multiple maps